# Reading A File, And Extracting Each Line As It's Own Variable [Bash]

Tags: string, bash, file, variables, grep

I've been stuck on this, and can't seem to find any good tips on getting this to work.
Okay, so I have this file called "tweets" which has a couple hundred lines.  I need to get each line as it's own variable.

Example:

```
   root@host:~$ cat tweets
   this is line one
   this is line two
   this is line three
```

Alright, so I need each line to be set as a variable.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done < tweets
```

Comment: So is the variable automatically set to "$line", or do I have to set it?

Answer (score 1):

In bash, use `mapfile` to read the file into an array:

```
$ mapfile -t var < tweets
$ echo "${var[0]}"
   this is line one
$ echo "${var[2]}"
   this is line three
```

Comment: Is is BASH 4+ feature since I don't have it on `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release`

Comment: Don't know. Can you do: `a=(1); a+=(2)` ? Otherwise I'd do `while read  -r line; do var[i++]=$line; done < file`

Comment: Then: `while read -r line; do var+=("$line"); done < file`. Of course, this is all assuming the OP needs to have all the lines stored, as opposed to your answer.

Comment: I wasn't sure about storing part either.